# How "Math.random() * arr.length | 0" works for return a random index for an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I've been working in a legacy code that have a certain functionality that should return a random item for array and I see the following expression:

```
array[Math.random() * arr.length | 0]
```

My first impression was try to undestand [the `|` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR) but i can't figure out how does work. 
I test the expression in the chrome console and I see that always returns a valid index with this:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4]
for(let i = 0; i < 5000; i++){
   console.log(array[Math.random() * arr.length | 0]);
}
```

**How "Math.random() * arr.length | 0" works for return a random index for an array?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `Math.random()` returns a number >= 0 and < 1.
- `* arr.length` returns a number >= 0 and < arr.length, yet this can't be used as an index, because it would have a fractional part
- `| 0` coerces the left expression to a integral number then applies the bitwise or with the number zero, which is always the other number

This said, what makes this work is the implicit conversion (called coersion) in the operator `|`.

Comment: Oh! it's only a hack for coerse to int number!! thanks!

Comment: Yeap, and as it is, it'd be preferable to use `Math.trunc()` instead, much clearer in intention.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, `| 0` is being used to round down to the nearest integer. So Math.random generates a number in the range 0 <= number < 1, then this gets multiplied by arr.length giving a number between 0 <= number < arr.length, which is then rounded down giving an integer between 0 and arr.length -1, inclusive

Answer (score -1):

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

function randomIndex() {
let random = Math.floor(Math.random () * array.length)
return array [random]
}
console.log(randomIndex())
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32089035)